# Kubectl command to check if namespace is ready

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to know if there is a command in kubernetes that returns true if all resources in a namespace have the ready status and false otherwise.

Something similar to this (ficticious) command:

```
kubectl get namespace <namespace-name> readiness
```

If there is not one such command, any help guiding me in the direction of how to retrieve this information (if all resources are ready in a given namespace) is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such command. try the below command to check all running pods

```
kubectl get po -n <namespace> | grep 'Running\|Completed'
```

below command to check the pods that are failed,terminated, error etc.

```
kubectl get po -n <namespace> | grep -v Running |grep -v Completed
```

Comment: probably also add to filter out cron jobs (status = Completed). ```kubectl get po -n <namespace> | grep 'Running \| Completed``` and ```kubectl get po -n <namespace> | grep -v Running |grep -v Completed```

Answer (score 4):

`kubectl get ns ${namespace} -o json | jq .status.phase -r` and if it is ready it will return status Active

Answer (score 3):

With the following sh scirpt, it is possible to check if all pods in a given namespace are running:

```
allRunning() {
    podStatus=$(kubectl get pods -n <namespace> -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="ContainersReady")].status}{"\n"}{end}')
    for elem in $podStatus
    do
        echo $elem
        if [ $elem != "Running" ]
        then
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}
allRunning
allAreRunning=$

if [ $allAreRunning == 1 ] 
then
    echo "all are running"
else
    echo "not ready"
fi
```

EDIT 1:
As suggested in the comments, pods do not seem to be the correct resource type to check readiness against. Thus, I suggest the following command for querying readiness which is based on deployment availability:

```
kubectl get deployments -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Available")].status}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Comment: Pods are ephemeral. They come and go all the time.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer, do you think the suggest solution works?